# Не деплоится rails приложение на heroku

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

У меня был проект на sqlite. Для heroku нужен postres. Я установил postres на mac os, после добавил `gem 'pg'` сделал `bundle install` и с горем пополам гем стал. Далее отредактировал `datadase.yml` залил на git и пытаюсь сделать `git push heroku master` 
Выдает ошибку.
Мой `database.yml`:

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: MYTODOLIST_development
pool: 5
username: 
password: 
timeout: 5000

test:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: MYTODOLIST_development
pool: 5
username: 
password: 
timeout: 5000
```

[image: это примерно в середине]

[image: в конце]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, тут такая штука: heroku очень специфический хостинг. Не знаю, как сейчас, но лет 5 назад у них был свой cron, свои менеджеры пакетов, ограниченный Postgres, преднастроенное окружение и так далее. В это облако легко и быстро деплоится Rails, ваша ошибка наверняка тоже просто решается, но, например, я в самом начале изучения Rails и деплоя понял, что изучаю не Rails, а heroku и не факт, что знания о конкретном хостинге мне потом пригодятся. Поэтому я купил какой-то VPS за условные 150р. и как все остальное человечество поднимал Rails с нуля на отдельной удаленной виртуалке.

Если вы намерены продолжать на heroku, то ошибка ассетов скорее всего в том, что в скрипте вы два раза пытаетесь подключить один и тот же файл. Может быть копипаста, нужно заглянуть во внутрь и посмотреть. В ssh-консоли выполните `cat путь/до/проблемного/файла.js` и посмотрите, не дублируется ли строка с подключением.

Вот подробная статья, по шагам раскрывающая особенности деплоя на heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ) Уже сделал, но Вы указали правильно: ""что в скрипте вы два раза пытаетесь подключить один и тот же файл"